# If $a^p+b^q+c^r=a^q+b^r+c^p=a^r+b^p+c^q$ .prove that $ a=b=c$ or $p=q=r$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Let $$a,b,c,p,q,r$$ be positive integers such that :

$$a^p+b^q+c^r=a^q+b^r+c^p=a^r+b^p+c^q$$

How do I prove :$ a=b=c$ or $p=q=r$ ?

Thank you for any kind of help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you elaborate more on how/where you're stuck? This would make it easier for people to give a solution that doesn't explain stuff you already know, and just adds whatever new insights are required to get a solution.

Comment: I deduced it from diophantian equation,and it's seems to me true about the equility of exponents positive integers .

Comment: and no attempt it's look hard for me,i'm affraid from d.equation

Comment: If you aren't mathematically certain that this is true (i.e., you don't have a proof), and if you haven't seen it stated as a fact from a reputable math source, you should indicate that. In that case there's always the chance that it's false.

Comment: if i have a source where is the problem to indicate it ?

Comment: If you have a source, that will make everyone more comfortable that this really is true so they can focus on helping you prove it, rather than wasting some time trying to find a counter example in parallel.

Comment: thank you for your helpful  comments .In way if it is true that's good to all and if it is false seems the counter-example appear in the first view

Answer (score 1):

The case when all of $a,b,c$ are not distinct is straightforward, as well as the cases when not all of $p,q,r$ are different.

Assume $a>b>c$ and assume $p> q,r$.

Case $1$ is when $p>q> r$. In this case clearly $a^p+b^q+c^r$ is strictly larger than any possible combination.

Case $2$ is when $p>r>q$

In this case clearly $a^q+b^r+c^p$ is smaller than any other combination.